# Compare elements of one array to other two arrays, swift

Tags: swift5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25k2I.png)

I wanted to check if the value array I passed in will be matched or contain the value to the alphabets array, nums array, or both.

the intention of checking this was meant to make a login validation, and I do not want to use the regular expression way to check it, instead I would like to use the current function or loops to solve this question.

the enclosed picture was the approach i have tried. I may have gotten the wrong direction.

Comment: Please copy the corresponding code to your questions. Links (like your image-link) expire and may not be accessible later.

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? Are you facing any crashes, error etc. please specify and instead of adding a picture with code please add the code itself here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `for character in convertedCharaters` picks each elem of the array, it will either be in `alphabets` or in `nums` but not in both for sure. That's the mistake in your code.

Here we define to flags (`numFound` - true if there was a num, `letterFound` - true if there was a letter) and iterate through all elements of the given array.

If the element is contained by `alphabets`, we set the `result` and set the `letterFound = true`. If the for-loop already found a `num`, the flag `numFound` has to be `true`. Therefore we know that we found both (letter and number), so we can instantly `return "contains both"`.

Same approach if the element is contained by `nums`.

```swift
var result = ""
var numFound = false
var letterFound = false
for character in convertedCharaters {
  if alphabets.contain(character) {
    result = "contains only letter"
    letterFound = true
    if numFound {
      return = "contains both"
    }
  } else if nums.contains(characters) {
    result = "contains only nums"
    numFound = true
    if letterFound {
      return = "contains both"
    }
  }
}

return result
```

Be careful about the case that neither num nor letter was found! I did not consider that.